# Could not play shockwave flash object (swf)

Tags: windows, video, flash, swf

I have shockwave flash object file (.swf) and it's corresponding meta file. But I can't play it in either Internet Explorer or Mozilla Firefox 3.0.11. I tried to install Adobe Shockwave player. Still, I can't play the swf file. As far as I know and remember, I can play this file type in most web browsers.

I am using Windows XP Professional SP 3.

My question is : What are the things I need to check/do so I can play this type of file?

Comment: what sort of result do you get when you open it in your browser?  blank screen?  error message?  etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find free swf players around the net but if the file is fine you might find it is not associated with a web browser etc...you might want to look at what its associated with in windows...

one way to do this is to open explorer > Tools > Folder Options > File Types tab

scroll down and find swf and check the association

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Most SWF files can be played with the Flash player.  It sounds like it might be a corrupted file rather than a problem with your machine.  Can you download and view other SWF files now?  Try this one, for instance: http://www.britarch.ac.uk/caf/wikka.php?wakka=TestSWF

Answer (score 1):

SWF files are usually just standard Flash files. Do not do file open in your browser, but instead try just dragging the SWF file in to your browser window.

If it does not work, try updating your flash version - however, I have not seen shockwave needed for many years.